# Overriding with classes in material-ui v1.0.0-beta-1 shows "the key provided to the classes property is not implemented" warning

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to override the styling of Material-UI v1 components, using the [overriding by classes](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/customization/overrides#overriding-with-classes) method.

When I try to override a nested property, for example the *:hover* pseudo class on the *root* key I get the following warning:

```
Warning: Material-UI: the key `.MyButton-root-w:hover` provided to
the classes property object is not implemented in Button.
You can only overrides one of the following:
```

See for example:

```
import React from "react";
import { createStyleSheet, withStyles } from "material-ui/styles";
import Button from "material-ui/Button";

const buttonStyle = createStyleSheet("MyButton", {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "#f99",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#99f"
    }
  }
});

export default withStyles(buttonStyle)(Button);
```

Or see it in action at https://codesandbox.io/s/gRgGrYvr

As the example button does get a different background color when hovering, I was wondering if this is an issue in Material-UI or if I don't yet fully grasp how to override its styling.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @kybarg who helped me on [Material-UI's Gitter](https://gitter.im/callemall/material-ui) I know how to fix this, see the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gLwOrYBzr) he made to help me.

The warning occurs because the classes property will next to the root key also contain a `.MyButton-root-p:hover` property which the Button *obviously* doesn't support. To solve this make sure you only pass the supported keys to the Button, for example by:

```
export default withStyles(buttonStyle)(({ classes, ...restProps}) => (
  <Button classes={{ root: classes.root }} {...restProps} />
));
```

Comment: how would you ensure this works with react/typescript? I get the same error with Material UI paper, and it is not clear how to fix it. See here for my full code: https://gist.github.com/daneasterman/cc8e9ebe58c60d825f8f3762c572cf91

Comment: Sorry the full error is: Material-UI: the key `.Component-root-199:hover` provided to the classes property object is not implemented in Paper.
You can only overrides one of the following: root,rounded,shadow0,shadow1,shadow2,shadow3,shadow4,shadow5,shadow6,shadow7,shadow8,shadow9,shadow10,shadow11,shadow12,shadow13,shadow14,shadow15,shadow16,shadow17,shadow18,shadow19,shadow20,shadow21,shadow22,shadow23,shadow24