# Material UI: "The key provided to the classes property is not implemented"

Tags: material-ui

I am using the withStyles() HOC to override some Material UI component styles, theme and breakpoints.

There is obviously something I do not understand here as I keep getting errors such as this one:

> Warning: Material-UI: the key `tab` provided to the classes property
> is not implemented in Items.

> You can only override one of the following:
> card,details,content,cover,avatar,lock

Example code: https://codesandbox.io/s/6xwz50kxn3

I have a `<List />` component and its child `<Items />`.

My intention is to apply the styles in the demo.js file only to the `<List />` component, and the styles in the demoChild.js to the `<Items />` Component.

I would really appreciate an explanation of what I'm doing wrong, and maybe a solution?

Note: I have found [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284597/overriding-with-classes-in-material-ui-v1-0-0-beta-1-shows-the-key-provided-to) with the same error, but they seem to have something different from my example.

Comment: I'd be totally fine with using straight styles, no overrides, but i cannot seem to be able to use `[theme.breakpoints.up('xs')]: {...}` without getting an error like this: `Unsupported style property @media (min-width:0px). Did you mean @media (minWidth:0px)?`

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The warnings are caused by this line in your demo.js file:

```
<Items {...this.props} items={items} />
```

You're spreading all of `List`'s props down into your `Items`. One of these props is `classes`, containing all of the CSS classes you define in demo.js. Since those are intended for `List`, they include CSS classes that are implemented by `List` but not `Items`. Since `Items` is receiving this prop, it's reading it as you trying to override classes that aren't available and warning you about it.

You can fix this problem by spreading only the unused props:

```
// Use other to capture only the props you're not using in List
const { classes, headerIsHidden, ...other } = this.props;

// Then spread only those unused props
<Items {...other} items={items} /
```

Then, you won't be spreading `classes` object into `Items`, so you won't get any warnings about classes that aren't implemented.

Comment: Now that I read your answer I am kicking myself for not seeing it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it fixed my problem too.

Comment: What if I have other classes object and I wanted to override from props?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I want to reuse multiple styles in different files, so I wrote a helper function:

```js
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
    
// Fixed: material-ui "The key provided to the classes property is not implemented"
const withMultipleStyles = (...params) => {
   return withStyles((theme) => {
        var styles = {}
        for (var len = params.length, key = 0; key < len; key++) {
            styles = Object.assign(styles, params[key](theme));
        }

        return styles
    })
}
  
export default withMultipleStyles
```

Usage:

```js
import React from 'react'
import compose from 'recompose/compose'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { style1, style2, withMultipleStyles } from '../../styles'

class your_class_name_here extends React.Component {
     // your implementation
}

export default compose(
   withMultipleStyles(style1, style2),
   withWidth(),
   connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(your_class_name_here)
```

[image: Edit wz0vvqmkw5]

Comment: Could you please provide a simple code sandbox example?

Comment: @dauffret , I added the demo on Code Sandbox above