# Material-UI: The key `wrapper` provided to the classes prop is not implemented in undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a project and in this project I have several interfaces and among these interfaces there is an interface to create a table and this table contains a set of data, but I got this error:

```
Material-UI: The key `wrapper` provided to the classes prop is not implemented in undefined.
```

How can i solve the problem?

This file contains the content of the table

jobsTable.js:

```
    import { forwardRef, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
    import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
    import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
    import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
    import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
    import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
    import TablePagination from "@material-ui/core/TablePagination";
    import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
    import TableSortLabel from "@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel";
    import {
      useGlobalFilter,
      usePagination,
      useRowSelect,
      useSortBy,
      useTable,
    } from "react-table";
    import clsx from "clsx";
    import JobsTablePaginationActions from "./JobsTablePaginationActions";
    
    const IndeterminateCheckbox = forwardRef(({ indeterminate, ...rest }, ref) => {
      const defaultRef = useRef();
      const resolvedRef = ref || defaultRef;
    
      useEffect(() => {
        resolvedRef.current.indeterminate = indeterminate;
      }, [resolvedRef, indeterminate]);
    
      return (
        <>
          <Checkbox ref={resolvedRef} {...rest} />
        </>
      );
    });
    
    const EnhancedTable = ({ columns, data, onRowClick }) => {
      const {
        getTableProps,
        headerGroups,
        prepareRow,
        page,
        gotoPage,
        setPageSize,
        state: { pageIndex, pageSize },
      } = useTable(
        {
          columns,
          data,
          autoResetPage: true,
        },
        useGlobalFilter,
        useSortBy,
        usePagination,
        useRowSelect,
        (hooks) => {
          hooks.allColumns.push((_columns) => [
            // Let's make a column for selection
            {
              id: "selection",
              sortable: false,
              // The header can use the table's getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps method
              // to render a checkbox.  Pagination is a problem since this will select all
              // rows even though not all rows are on the current page.  The solution should
              // be server side pagination.  For one, the clients should not download all
              // rows in most cases.  The client should only download data for the current page.
              // In that case, getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps works fine.
              Header: ({ getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps }) => (
                <div>
                  <IndeterminateCheckbox {...getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps()} />
                </div>
              ),
              // The cell can use the individual row's getToggleRowSelectedProps method
              // to the render a checkbox
              Cell: ({ row }) => (
                <div>
                  <IndeterminateCheckbox
                    {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()}
                    onClick={(ev) => ev.stopPropagation()}
                  />
                </div>
              ),
            },
            ..._columns,
          ]);
        }
      );
    
      const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
        gotoPage(newPage);
      };
    
      const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
        setPageSize(Number(event.target.value));
      };
    
      // Render the UI for your table
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            // padding: "2rem",
            border: "solid 1px #e8e4e4",
          }}
          className="flex flex-col min-h-full sm:rounded-16 overflow-hidden"
        >
          <TableContainer className="flex flex-1">
            <Table {...getTableProps()}>
              <TableHead>
                {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
                  <TableRow {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                    {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                      <TableCell
                        className="whitespace-nowrap p-4 md:p-12"
                        {...(!column.sortable
                          ? column.getHeaderProps()
                          : column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps()))}
                      >
                        {column.render("Header")}
                        {column.sortable ? (
                          <TableSortLabel
                            active={column.isSorted}
                            // react-table has a unsorted state which is not treated here
                            direction={column.isSortedDesc ? "desc" : "asc"}
                          />
                        ) : null}
                      </TableCell>
                    ))}
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {page.map((row, i) => {
                  prepareRow(row);
                  return (
                    <TableRow
                      {...row.getRowProps()}
                      onClick={(ev) => onRowClick(ev, row)}
                      className="truncate cursor-pointer"
                    >
                      {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                        return (
                          <TableCell
                            {...cell.getCellProps()}
                            className={clsx("p-4 md:p-12", cell.column.className)}
                          >
                            {cell.render("Cell")}
                          </TableCell>
                        );
                      })}
                    </TableRow>
                  );
                })}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
          <TablePagination
            component="div"
            classes={{
              root: "flex-shrink-0 border-t-1",
            }}
            rowsPerPageOptions={[
              5,
              10,
              25,
              { label: "All", value: data.length + 1 },
            ]}
            colSpan={5}
            count={data.length}
            rowsPerPage={pageSize}
            page={pageIndex}
            SelectProps={{
              inputProps: { "aria-label": "rows per page" },
              native: false,
            }}
            onPageChange={handleChangePage}
            onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
            ActionsComponent={JobsTablePaginationActions}
          />
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    EnhancedTable.propTypes = {
      columns: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
      data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
      onRowClick: PropTypes.func,
    };
    
    export default EnhancedTable;
```

This file contains the header of the table

jobLists.js:

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import FuseUtils from "@fuse/utils";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { useMemo, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { deleteJob } from "./store/jobsSlice";
import JobsMultiSelectMenu from "./JobsMultiSelectMenu";
import JobsTable from "./JobsTable";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Slide from "@material-ui/core/Slide";
import {
  openEditJobDialog,
  removeContact,
  toggleStarredContact,
  selectJobs,
} from "./store/jobsSlice";
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  button1: {
    backgroundColor: "none",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#43a047",
      color: "#e8e4e4",
      transition: "0.3s",
      borderColor: "#43a047",
    },
  },
  button2: {
    backgroundColor: "none",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#e53935",
      color: "#e8e4e4",
      transition: "0.3s",
      borderColor: "#e53935",
    },
  },
});

// const onRejectUser = useCallback((id) => {
//   dispatch(rejectUser(id));
// }, []);

function JobsList(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const contacts = useSelector(selectJobs);
  const searchText = useSelector(({ jobsApp }) => jobsApp.jobs.searchText);
  const user = useSelector(({ jobsApp }) => jobsApp.user);
  const { selectedJobsIds } = props;

  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState(null);

  const { enqueueSnackbar, closeSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  const handleClick = () => {
    enqueueSnackbar(
      "User accepted",
      { variant: "success" },
      {
        anchorOrigin: {
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "right",
        },
      },
      { TransitionComponent: Slide }
    );
  };

  const deleteJobHandleClick = () => {
    enqueueSnackbar(
      "Job Deleted successfully",
      { variant: "error" },
      {
        anchorOrigin: {
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "right",
        },
      },
      { TransitionComponent: Slide }
    );
  };

  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "ID",
        accessor: "id",
        className: "font-medium",
        sortable: true,
        align: "left",
      },
      {
        Header: "Job Title",
        accessor: "name",
        className: "font-medium",
        sortable: true,
        align: "center",
      },
      {
        Header: "Description",
        accessor: "description",
        sortable: true,
        align: "center",
      },

      {
        id: "action",
        // width: 128,
        align: "right",
        sortable: false,
        Cell: ({ row }) => (
          <div className="flex items-center">
            {/* <IconButton
              onClick={(ev) => {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                dispatch(approveUser(row.original.id));
                dispatch(toggleStarredContact(row.original.id));
                handleClick(ev);
                dispatch(toggleStarredContact(row.original.id));
              }}
              style={{ color: "green", border: "none" }}
            >
              <Icon>edit</Icon>
            </IconButton> */}
            <IconButton
              onClick={(ev) => {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                dispatch(deleteJob(row.original.id));
                deleteJobHandleClick(ev);
              }}
              // className={classes.button2}
              style={{ color: "red", border: "none" }}
            >
              <Icon>delete</Icon>
            </IconButton>
          </div>
        ),
      },
    ],
    [dispatch, user.starred]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    function getFilteredArray(entities, _searchText) {
      if (_searchText.length === 0) {
        return contacts;
      }
      return FuseUtils.filterArrayByString(contacts, _searchText);
    }

    if (contacts) {
      setFilteredData(getFilteredArray(contacts, searchText));
    }
  }, [contacts, searchText]);

  if (!filteredData) {
    return null;
  }

  if (filteredData.length === 0) {
    return (
      <div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-center h-full">
        <Typography color="textSecondary" variant="h5">
          There are no Jobs!
        </Typography>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <motion.div
      initial={{ y: 20, opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ y: 0, opacity: 1, transition: { delay: 0.2 } }}
    >
      <JobsTable
        columns={columns}
        data={filteredData}
        onRowClick={(ev, row) => {
          if (row) {
            dispatch(openEditJobDialog(row.original));
          }
        }}
      />
    </motion.div>
  );
}

export default JobsList;
```

Comment: I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936467/material-ui-the-key-provided-to-the-classes-property-is-not-implemented). In `jobsTable.js` you destruct `getToggleRowSelectedProps()` into `IndeterminateCheckbox`. Do you think there might be some props that you're passing down to `IndeterminateCheckbox` that you shouldn't be? Btw the code looks really neat, a pleasure to read

Comment: ok, how to solve it?, i don't understand what is the problem

Comment: What is being returned from `getToggleRowSelectedProps()` and what is the definition of `IndeterminateCheckbox`? I could be completely wrong, but that's what feels like could be the problem.

Comment: The header can use the table's getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps method
          to render a checkbox.  Pagination is a problem since this will select all
          rows even though not all rows are on the current page.  The solution should
          be server side pagination.  For one, the clients should not download all
          rows in most cases.  The client should only download data for the current page.
          In that case, getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps works fine.

Comment: The cell can use the individual row's getToggleRowSelectedProps method
          to the render a checkbox